# how to convert xls to xml in android

Tags: android

Recently i am working with reading excel file and need to show it on android view.
I  have even tried with both the java libraries say apache poi and jexcel api which helps 
in parsing excel sheet in java but failed to parse in android when i tried.

I am even tried with converting excel to xml,than parse the xml and show the contents
on android view but for this i have needed convertor which converts .xls to .xml. 
Can anybody help me in parsing excel file in android.

Thanks And Regards
Pinkesh Gupta

Answer (score 0):

`jxl` can be used in Android but it only supports *xls* format not *xlsx*.

While `poi` supports both. But when used in Android, you can only read *xls* file using `HSSFWorkbook`. For reading *xlsx* file you need `XSSFWorkbook`, but there is a issue when using `XSSFWorkbook` in Android (see [this](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/poi-dev/201110.mbox/%3CCA+JOeWNWinmNmEtHs5VK+KEc_6BzAG_=LfpdXqsDsnjJKR2X7Q@mail.gmail.com%3E)).